# displaying only one product per row

Tags: extensions, css

we used some marketplace extension , so

here in this following link, you can see only 1 product is displaying per row.

i want to display 3 products per row .

http://hotwheelstoys.in/totaltoys2/var/www/html/totaltoys/marketplace/seller/collection/kidsdial2

is there any css problem with that page as it is displaying only one per product per row?

please help me to display 3 products per row and help me to display "add to cart" button below as like here :

http://hotwheelstoys.in/totaltoys2/var/www/html/totaltoys/girls-toys.html

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a fieldset with 49% width which is causing this behavior. Make an appropriate change for listing pages and you'll see three products per row.

[image]